DataStreamWriter.writeBytes(NativeArray<bytes>) throwing object not set to instance of an object error
So I Have A "Packet" That I've Serialized Into A List And Now I Need Help Transforming It Into A Native Array To Send Over The DataStreamWriter
Heres My Code So Far
clientPacket = new Packet(1, Vector3.one, Vector3.one, Vector3.one, new bool[3], 100);
List<byte> PacketBytes = clientPacket.Serialize();
NativeArray<byte> PacketBytesArray = new NativeArray<byte>(PacketBytes.ToArray(), Allocator.Persistent);
m_Driver.BeginSend(NetworkPipeline.Null, m_Connection, out var writer);
writer.WriteBytes(PacketBytesArray);
m_Driver.EndSend(writer);
PacketBytesArray.Dispose();

And I Get The Error

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
object Unity.Collections.DataStreamWriter.WriteBytesInternal
(System.Byte* data, System.Int32 bytes) (at
./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collections@2.2.1/Unity.Collections/DataStreamWriter.cs:283)
Unity.Collections.DataStreamWriter.WriteBytes
(Unity.Collections.NativeArray`1[T] value) (at
./Library/PackageCache/com.unity.collections@2.2.1/Unity.Collections/DataStreamWriter.cs:313)
ClientBehaviour.Update () (at
Assets/Scripts/Networking/ClientBehaviour.cs:58)

Line 58 Of Client Behaviour Is
writer.WriteBytes(PacketBytesArray);
